# EWS GetItem Request + IncludeMimeContent + Huge Mail = OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, exchangewebservices, large-data

I have an E-Mail in a Exchange 2007 mailbox that's 200 MB big. Don't ask me how it got that big; I don't know. But it's in a mailbox and it needs to get out in MIME format. To make it more challenging, it needs to get out in MIME format using EWS in C#.

In theory, it's a piece of cake, right? All I got to do is:

```
GetItemType getItemRequest = new GetItemType {
    ItemIds = new ItemIdType[] { sItemId },
    ItemShape = new ItemResponseShapeType {
        BaseShape = DefaultShapeNamesType.IdOnly,
        IncludeMimeContent = true,
        IncludeMimeContentSpecified = true,
        BodyType = BodyTypeResponseType.Best,
        BodyTypeSpecified = true
    }
};
```

... and then send it off:

```
GetItemResponseType getItemResponse = oService.GetItem(getItemRequest);
```

But with a 200 MB mail, real life hits you over the head pretty quick. My program explodes with a System.OutOfMemoryException after it ate up 2GB of memory. The stack trace points me to:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString()
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText()
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadStartElement()
Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderExchangeServiceBinding.Read75_MimeContentType(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderExchangeServiceBinding.Read139_MessageType(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderExchangeServiceBinding.Read302_ArrayOfRealItemsType(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderExchangeServiceBinding.Read310_ItemInfoResponseMessageType(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderExchangeServiceBinding.Read315_ArrayOfResponseMessagesType(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderExchangeServiceBinding.Read331_GetItemResponseType(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderExchangeServiceBinding.Read429_GetItemResponse()
Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer125.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
MyAwesomeApp.ExchangeService.ExchangeServiceBinding.GetItem(GetItemType GetItem1)
```

And sure enough, my 200 MB mail, as BASE64 encoded XML, is being read into RAM. And I guess to rub dirt into the wound it's probably stored in RAM several times by the various auto-generated methods that mess with it throughout the call stack.

The annoying thing, after I get my BASE64-encoded MIME message back from the method (works fine for smaller messages), the first thing I do is write it to disk and free the object that holds it to release memory. I already have code that uses FromBase64Transform to decode BASE64 as it is being read from disk. I wanted to prevent a horror scenario like this.

That being said, what can I do to avoid the XML response being processed in RAM? Ideally, I would like to write it by disk and then read it sequentially. Any idea how I can do this without having to roll my own SOAP client for EWS entirely?

Edit2: Previous edit didn't work either. Regenerating the web service class broke it. Oh well, back to square one.

Comment: ever find a solution to this? I am also having an issue with a large mailbox.